# Using javascript confirm box to authenticate user action

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with multiple items, and user can delete any of the items right there on the same page. But I need to integrate a javascript confirm alert box to authenticate if the user really wants to continue with the action for each item.

I was able to achieve it by placing the javascript in the page but the challenge is that I can only use just one javascript function to delete only one item. This simply means i would be having multiple javascript for each item and that is damn difficult because the number of these items cannot be defined as it keep increasing.

So I need to be able to use just one javascript function for all the items being displayed.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script>    

<!--
function confirmAlertBox(){
   var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
   if( retVal == true ){
  window.location = "items.php?del_item&amp;item_id=<?php echo $item_id; ?>";
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
//-->

</script>
```

Here are the items being fetch from the database:

```
<?php

while ($all_item_row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($all_item_query)) {
    $item_title = $all_item_row['title'];
    $item_id = $all_item_row['id'];

 echo '<tr> <td>'.$item_title.'</td> <td class="action_lnk"><a href="edit_item.php?edit_cal&amp;item_id='.$item_id.'">Edit Item</a> <a href="#" onclick="confirmAlertBox()">Delete Item</a> <div class="clear"></div></td> </tr>';

}
}
else{
echo "<strong>No item available. Thank You!</strong>";  
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the separate function all together and go with something a bit simpler.

When you are building your table cell, change the Delete link to:

```
<a href="items.php?del_item&amp;item_id='.$item_id.'" 
   onclick="return confirm('Do you want to Delete this item?');">
       Delete Item
</a>
```

*Not sure how you escape the ' character in php, so you would need to do this in the confirm function*

That way the link is in the anchor already and the user will be sent to this link if they click ok. Otherwise `false` will be returned and the user will stay where they are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href=\"javascript:confirmDelete('items.php?del_item&amp;item_id=$item_id;')\">Delete</a>
```

and your javascript function should be like

```
<script>

function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")) {
document.location = delUrl;
 }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function as

```
function confirmAlertBox(id){
   var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
   if( retVal == true ){
  window.location = "items.php?del_item&amp;item_id="+id;
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

Then call it using `confirmAlertBox(<?php echo $item_id; ?>)` instead of `confirmAlertBox()`.